# matplotlib, draw multiple graphs / points in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

I am trying to develop a telemetry system which sends sensor data from an Arduino, plotted in realtime. For this I'm using Python and the matplotlib-library. **My problem is that every time a new data point arrives, I want to add that data point by plotting it into the same figure as the other data points.** So far I could not find a solution to this.

Comment: Use `set_data`. See for example [this mpl example](http://matplotlib.org/dev/examples/animation/bayes_update.html); it uses an animation, but wheter the data comes in from an animation or a sensor doesn't matter much in this context.

Comment: Unfortunately Matlab doesn't have the equivalent of the Dynamic function in Mathematica.

Comment: so, i've tried the set_data function from the Example Evert sent me. This works quite ok, however it's still a little to slow, to plot every new data point for itself. I'm recieving new data points with about 5-10 Hz, so the call to draw() produces a bottleneck. My solution now, is to always gather 10 data points and plot them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream data from an Arduino into a Plotly graph with the Arduino API in Plotly. You have two options: continuously transmit data (which it sounds like you'll want to do), or transmit a single chunk.

It will update the graph every few seconds if you refresh the page.

The Arduino API is available [here](http://plot.ly/api/arduino). And, if you're already using Python, you can use the `extend` option to update data into another plot. The Python API is [here](http://plot.ly/api/python).

Here's an example of how it looks to transmit from an Arduino, and you can see the interactive version [here](https://plot.ly/~flann321/9/)

[image]

Full disclosure: I work at Plotly.

Answer (score -1):

as far as I can see, you have a few different ways of doing this (i'll list them in what I consider increasing difficulty

1. Making a bitmap file, eg .png, which has to be regenerated each time a new datapoint arrives. To do this you need to have your old data stored somewhere in a file or in a database.
2. Using svg in a browser. Then you can add on points or lines using javascript (e.g. http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=1506 )
3. Make a bitmap, store it and edit it to add in new points - this really gets tricky if you either wants to "roll old points off" at one end, or rescale the image when more data arrives.
4. Make a series of bitmaps, and have the total graph as a combination of a lot of slices. - here you can easily "roll off" old points, but you are out of luck if you want to rescale.

Comment: This is all horribly complicated. You could simply overplot the current axes, or update the data using `set_data`. svg/javascript doesn't come in anywhere, it's matplotlib. And bitmaps are likely also not applicable: it sounds like a (vector) graph is produced, not a bitmap.